JavaFX 17: Change checkbox style of specific CheckBoxTreeCell instances
I have a CheckBoxTreeView that shows a log folder directory tree and allows the user to select which of these are shown in a TableView.  The log files/folders are actively being created/updated while the program is running so I'm listening for updates and showing these to the user but so far I can only address the CheckBoxTreeCell.
What I'd like to do is change the TreeCell checkbox border and/or background to indicate item updates.
Based on this question and solution: update CheckBoxTreeCell styles from outside process I am just adding and removing styles to the CheckBoxTreeCell:
   private void updateCell(CheckBoxTreeCell<LogFile> cell) {
        cell.getStyleClass().removeAll(Arrays.asList("logfile-created", "logfile-deleted", 
                "logfile-updated", "logfile-nochange"));
        LogFile logfile = cell.getItem();
        if (logfile != null) {
            LogStateEnum state = logfile.getState();
            // Update style class
            switch (state) {
            case CREATED:
                cell.getStyleClass().add("logfile-created");
                break;
            case DELETED:
                cell.getStyleClass().add("logfile-deleted");            
                break;
            case UPDATED:
                cell.getStyleClass().add("logfile-updated");
                Services.getLogService().debug(THIS_CLASS, MARKER, "styles - [" + Arrays.toString(cell.getStyleClass().toArray()) + "]");
                break;
            default:
                cell.getStyleClass().add("logfile-nochange");
                Services.getLogService().debug(THIS_CLASS, MARKER, logfile + " has styles - [" + Arrays.toString(cell.getStyleClass().toArray()) + "]");
            }
        }
    }


And the CSS:
.root {
    -default-text-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    -default-text-entry-color: rgb(105,105,105);
    -default-window-color: rgb(0,0,0);

}
.tree-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -default-window-color;
    -fx-text-fill: -default-text-color;
}

.tree-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -default-text-entry-color;
    -fx-text-fill: -default-window-color;
}

.tree-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -default-text-entry-color;
    -fx-text-fill: -default-window-color;
}

.logfile-updated {
    -fx-text-fill: green ;
}

.logfile-deleted {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}

.logfile-created {
    -fx-text-fill: yellow ;
}

.logfile-nochange {
    -fx-text-fill: -default-text-color;
}


I'm unable to change the style of the embedded checkbox.  How is this done?

@jewelsea Thanks so much!  That's exactly what I needed.

Replaced comments with an answer.

Examples of styling checkboxes are in modena.css.
You need to have the CSS style rule apply to the check box, not the cell, for non-inherited CSS styles like -fx-text-fill, e.g.
.logfile-created > .check-box { 
    -fx-text-fill: yellow; 
} 

Only the CSS file should need to change, I think your Java code should be OK.
The asker confirmed in comments, that this approach worked.
